# Why sphinxcontib-httpdomain directive http:post is unknown?

Tags: python-sphinx

I have trouble with sphinxcontrib-httpdomain. If i defining http get or post or any another domain, sphinx-build tells me about error

> Unknown directive type "http:get"

Definition of http:post domain in my sources:

```
.. http:get:: /users/(int:user_id)/posts/(tag)

   The posts tagged with `tag` that the user (`user_id`) wrote.

   **Example request**:

   .. sourcecode:: http

      GET /users/123/posts/web HTTP/1.1
      Host: example.com
      Accept: application/json, text/javascript

   **Example response**:

   .. sourcecode:: http

      HTTP/1.1 200 OK
      Vary: Accept
      Content-Type: text/javascript

      [
        {
          "post_id": 12345,
          "author_id": 123,
          "tags": ["server", "web"],
          "subject": "I tried Nginx"
        },
        {
          "post_id": 12346,
          "author_id": 123,
          "tags": ["html5", "standards", "web"],
          "subject": "We go to HTML 5"
        }
      ]

   :query sort: one of ``hit``, ``created-at``
   :query offset: offset number. default is 0
   :query limit: limit number. default is 30
   :reqheader Accept: the response content type depends on
                      :mailheader:`Accept` header
   :reqheader Authorization: optional OAuth token to authenticate
   :resheader Content-Type: this depends on :mailheader:`Accept`
                            header of request
   :statuscode 200: no error
   :statuscode 404: there's no user
```

There are two blank lines before and after this block. I tried to use 3,4 spaces and  to offset contents of block

Contents of extensions block of conf.py:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc',
            'sphinx.ext.extlinks',
            'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
            'sphinx.ext.todo',
            'sphinx.ext.coverage',
            'sphinx.ext.ifconfig',
            'sphinx.ext.doctest',
            'sphinx.ext.graphviz',
            'sphinxcontrib.httpdomain'
            ]
```

What i'd tried also and it doesn't helped:
- To reinstall all sphinx* packages via pip

- To reinstall all sphinx* packages via apt-get
- To specify path to extension in conf.py
- To reinstall all autodoc, docutils packages via pip
- To build on another host (same error)
- To look at build logs with -vvv mode
- To read [official plugin docs][3] and do all of steps

Some information which can be useful:

All packages are installed to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

pip show sphinx output:

```
Name: Sphinx
Version: 1.6.7
Summary: Python documentation generator
Home-page: http://sphinx-doc.org/
Author: Georg Brandl
Author-email: georg@python.org
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: sphinxcontrib-websupport, babel, imagesize, setuptools, typing, Pygments, requests, six, docutils, alabaster, Jinja2, snowballstemmer
```

pip show sphinxcontrib-httpdomain output:

```
Name: sphinxcontrib-httpdomain
Version: 1.6.0
Summary: Sphinx domain for documenting HTTP APIs
Home-page: https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/httpdomain
Author: Hong Minhee
Author-email: hong.minhee@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: six, Sphinx
```

uname output:

```
Linux 4.13.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 09:13:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please do not use pastebin. Use the standard Stack Overflow markup to display your code in your question. Your pastebin does not show reStructuredText that reflects the error message. Finally it is a good practice to install packages for a given project into a virtual environment to isolate package versions from one another. Otherwise you have a big blob of packages in an installed Python.

Comment: @StevePiercy Ok, i reformatted my post. Can you help me?) What else can i try? Is your only suggestion is to use virtualenv? What is the probability that it will help? I'm asking this question because of I haven't used virtualenv before and it can take me a long time

Comment: I told that it's the same error with any http:* (get, post, update, delete etc.)

Comment: Create a virtual environment, and install packages into it. Also `virtualenv` is the Python tool that is used to create virtual environments on Python 2.x. For Python 3.x, you would use `venv`, or `python -m venv <myVirtualEnvironmentName>`. It is a good idea to read the PyPA's Guides at https://packaging.python.org/guides/ to gain understanding about why virtual environments are the best practice for managing projects. Any guide that says `sudo pip install foo` leads to pain and suffering.

Comment: I have the same problem. My documentation started failing to build months ago and I can't find the cause. It was either some change in the sphinx configuration or an upgrade in one of the libraries.. But still no luck finding the cause...

Answer (score 0):

After fighting with this problem for a while, I finally found the solution. The version included in Debian buster and Ubuntu bionic (and newer) has a patch added which solved an issue, but added this problem.

The patch comes from [this commit](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/httpdomain/commit/50166fc7caedccf4ce1cd58a4d130a36f27eb739#diff-4c49a00847971a0a8bba1c81c32bf4f7), but it is missing the fix added a couple of days after in [this other commit](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/httpdomain/commit/8243bb6ec1ea0f3c96e0ed6177e743963fdd908b).

It seems that even if you tried to install with pip, you were using the system version. You can patch it trivially by editing the code at `/usr/lib/python2/dist-packages/sphinxcontrib/httpdomain.py`.

I am sending the patch to the package maintainer so it hopefully will be fixed soon in unstable.